# Switch statement calling all the cases in AsyncTask even if the variable is not matching

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I Created a AsyncTask with switch statement.Here Bothe the Test and Medicine case is called.Very strange Behaviour

```
    BackendAsync backendAsync = new BackendAsync();
    backendAsync.execute("Test");

public class BackendAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        switch (strings[0]){

            case "Test": {

                Log.d("Test", "doInBackground: Called Test");
            }
            case "Medicine": {

                Log.d("Medicine", "doInBackground: Called Medicine");
            }


        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Result:

> D/Test: doInBackground: Called Test  D/Medicine: doInBackground:
>   Called Medicine

Comment: you have to use break in each case.

Answer (score 1):

```
BackendAsync backendAsync = new BackendAsync();
    backendAsync.execute("Test");

public class BackendAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        switch (strings[0]){

            case "Test": {

                Log.d("Test", "doInBackground: Called Test");
            }
    break;
            case "Medicine": {

                Log.d("Medicine", "doInBackground: Called Medicine");
            }
    breakl


        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How this can be a correct answer. You have used break statement outside of case block.

Answer (score 0):

add break after every case

```
public class BackendAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        switch (strings[0]){

            case "Test": {

                Log.d("Test", "doInBackground: Called Test");
                  break;
            }
            case "Medicine": {

                Log.d("Medicine", "doInBackground: Called Medicine");
                  break;
            }


        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
 case "Test": {

            Log.d("Test", "doInBackground: Called Test");
            break;
        }
        case "Medicine": {

            Log.d("Medicine", "doInBackground: Called Medicine");
            break;
        }
```